# How to make AJAX synchronous

Tags: jquery, ajax

I know the nature of Ajax is the asynchronous, thus my code is wrong.
But I need help to find another solution.

Case is: I insert data into my database with:

```
 self.insertTextItem = function (item) {
    console.log("Insert TextItem with Service");
    return $.ajax({    
        type: "POST",
        url: serviceRoot + "InsertTextbatchTagItem",
        beforeSend: serviceFramework.setModuleHeaders,
        data: item,
        cache: false
    });
};

item.Id = null; // Id is autocreated in db.
item.Text = "Finally Friday!";

self.insertTextItem(item)     
    .done(function (newtext) {
                item.textbatchId = newtext.Id;
}

//continuous code…
```

This works find in most cases.
Exception is when I need the data returned from the database right away.
However I need the "continuous code" to wait for the Id to be returned.
The obvious solution is to place the "continuous code" into the callback-function, but as it is, I am calling self.insertTextItem in a function, thus the calling-function returns without waiting. (And obviously the callback function is ended within the calling function.)

How can I rewrite the self.insertTextItem-function in this case?

Comment: Implement the continuous code inside the `done()` callback.

Comment: @Asle making ajax synchronous can hang your application.If you want the data to be available when ajax call is done try using call back functions

Comment: the usual solution is to disable the ui, perhaps display an ajax spinner with an overlay, and re-enable in the ajax callback. synchronous ajax locks up the ui and makes for an unpleasant experience

Comment: I am using the callback-function, but the "continuous code" does´t wait as the "insertTextItem"-function is called from the view model.
Thus I need to replace AJAX with a synchronous function.

Comment: so refactor the 'continuous code' and call it from the ajax call back

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Exception is when I need the data returned from the database right away. However I need the "continuous code" to wait for the Id to be returned.

Your best bet is not to let that happen, but instead to embrace the event-driven, asynchronous nature of browser-based and network programming.

The **very much lesser option** is to force the ajax request to be synchronous. Currently, in jQuery 1.x, you can do that by adding `async: false` to your call; you'll also have to start using your own `$.Deferred` rather than the one you get from `ajax`, because as of jQuery 1.8, using `async: false` with the `jqXHR`'s built-in promise is deprecated. So:

```
self.insertTextItem = function (item, synchronous) { // <== Optional flag
    var deferred = $.Deferred();                     // <== Your own Deferred
    console.log("Insert TextItem with Service");
    $.ajax({    
        type: "POST",
        url: serviceRoot + "InsertTextbatchTagItem",
        beforeSend: serviceFramework.setModuleHeaders,
        data: item,
        cache: false,
        async: synchronous === true ? false : true,  // <=== Use it, ignoring `undefined` and othe rfalsey values
        success: function(data) {                    // Handling you Deferred
            deferred.resolveWith(data);              // (this is probably incomplete)
        },                                           //
        error: function() {                          //
            deferred.reject();                       //
        }                                            //
    });
    return deferred.promise();                       // Return the promise for your Deferred
};
```

That will make `insertTextItem` block (locking up the UI of most browsers) until the call completes. Because of the way jQuery's promises work, that will also make the `done` callback synchronous. (This is not true of many other promises implementations, but it is of jQuery's.)

That option uses the underlying features of `XMLHttpRequest`, which allow for synchronous ajax.

That option will also be going away in jQuery at some point.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the async property of $.ajax to false. By default it's true.

```
$.ajax({    
        type: "POST",
        async : false,
        url: serviceRoot + "InsertTextbatchTagItem",
        beforeSend: serviceFramework.setModuleHeaders,
        data: item,
        cache: false
    });
```

Comment: @op I urge you not to take this approach

Comment: @andrew, I do agree with you, that callback should be the ideal candidate for this kind of scenario.